# How to share Button's status from one activity to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, sharedpreferences

- Say there are 3 buttons in activity 1 and on clicking each button the
  color changes and also the texts.
- I want to save both the value using sharedpreference.
- Than take those value in 2 activity.
- Then we'll check if the buttons is clicked and buttons colors and text is changed.
- If it's changed then show 2 Buttons else show Text.

Answer (score 0):

If you save both values in sharedpreference than you can use that directly in second activity